# Compare Month and Year in Sql query

Tags: php, sql

I Want to compare only month and year in SQL Using PHP, but when I only use month and year in the SQL query the only result is 00-00-0000.

```
$mounth = date("Y-m", time());
$histmessql = "SELECT * FROM historico WHERE data = $mounth";
```

Comment: show an example of data in your column table ?

Comment: 2019-02-06
but i try $mounth = date("Y-m", time());

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Depending on your database, may be helpful to put quotes around your date.  Like "03-2019" instead of just 03-2019.

Comment: @bjk116 My guess would be that because of this, the query is `data = -2016`, right?

Comment: @Dharman Yea I know when I run stuff on MySQL I have to do timeColumn = "2019-03-08", not timeColumn = 2019-03-08

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to update your sql query to :

```
$histmessql = "SELECT * FROM historico WHERE data like  '%$mounth%'";
```

using = , this fetch a completed equality , while your have to use `like` , here is the examples :

- `WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'`   Finds any values that start with "a"
- `WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%a'`  Finds any values that end with "a"
- `WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%'` Finds any values that have "or" in any
  position
- `WHERE CustomerName LIKE '_r%'`  Finds any values that have "r" in the
  second position
- `WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a_%_%'`    Finds any values that start with "a"
  and are at least 3 characters in length
- `WHERE ContactName LIKE 'a%o'`   Finds any values that start with "a" and
  ends with "o"

Comment: Works!Tks sooo much

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `data` column in your database is any of the date/datetime. With that assumption, I think you can make use of the `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` function and your code could look like

```
$mounth = date("Y-m", time());
$histmessql = "SELECT * FROM historico WHERE DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y-%m') = '$mounth'";
```

You can read more
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format